# Why isn't a ShEx constant matching the same term in the data?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, shex

I have a ShEx schema expecting a specific type:

```
epri:VariableShape {
  a st:studyVariable ;
  st:subject [tax:~] ;
  st:signal xsd:decimal
}
```

which rejects data with that type

```
st:envFactorEMF a st:studyVariable ; # << this isn't recognized
  st:subject tax:1758 ;
  st:signal -.00043 .
```

([demo](http://rawgit.com/shexSpec/shex.js/master/doc/shex-simple.html?schema=PREFIX%20epri%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.epri.com%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20st%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.epri.com%2Fstudies%2F3002011786%3E%0APREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20tax%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Finfo.identifiers.org%2Ftaxonomy%2F%3E%0A%0Aepri%3AVariableShape%20%7B%0A%20%20a%20st%3AstudyVariable%20%3B%0A%20%20st%3Asubject%20%5Btax%3A~%5D%20%3B%0A%20%20st%3Asignal%20xsd%3Adecimal%0A%7D&data=PREFIX%20epri%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.epri.com%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20tax%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Finfo.identifiers.org%2Ftaxonomy%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20st%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.epri.com%2Fstudies%2F3002011786%3E%0A%0Ast%3AenvFactorEMF%20a%20st%3AstudyVariable%20%3B%0A%20%20st%3Asubject%20tax%3A1758%20%3B%0A%20%20st%3Asignal%20-.00043%20.&shape-map=%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.epri.com%2Fstudies%2F3002011786envFactorEMF%3E%40epri%3AVariableShape&interface=human&regexpEngine=threaded-val-nerr)) Why would that be?

Comment: I'm no ShExpert (sorry), but the specific error message that the validator provides is helpful. Just like `st:signal xsd:decimal` means that the value of the st:signal property is expected to be a literal with datatype xsd:decimal, it's expecting that the value for rdf:type will a literal that has datatype st:studyVariable. Of course, in the data, that value is actually the IRI st:studyVariable, not a literal at all.

Comment: I think you'd want to use `a [st:studyVariable]` to indicate that you want the actual value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message from the demo that you linked to actually describes the exact problem.

> Error validating http://www.epri.com/studies/3002011786studyVariable as {"type":"NodeConstraint","datatype":"http://www.epri.com/studies/3002011786studyVariable"}: mismatched datatype: http://www.epri.com/studies/3002011786studyVariable is not a literal with datatype http://www.epri.com/studies/3002011786studyVariable

You're using a [datatype constraint](http://shexspec.github.io/primer/#vocab-literal-datatype), which isn't what you want.

You need to use `a [ st:studyVariable ]`, instead, since you want to specify a [value set](http://shexspec.github.io/primer/#value-sets):

```
epri:VariableShape {
  a [ st:studyVariable ];
  st:subject [tax:~] ;
  st:signal xsd:decimal
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Joshua Taylor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46879443/8740436) is spot on but, since this is the most common mistake in ShEx, I thought I'd elaborate with a little ascii art.

ShEx datatypes are expressed as bare IRIs while value sets are expressed in `[]s`. You had an `rdf:type` of `st:studyVariable`:

```
epri:VariableShape {
  a st:studyVariable ;   # <-- datatype
  st:subject [tax:~] ;   # <-- value set
  st:signal xsd:decimal  # <-- datatype
}
```

when you wanted a (small) value set of `st:studyVariable`:

```
epri:VariableShape {
  a [st:studyVariable] ; # <-- value set
  st:subject [tax:~] ;   # <-- value set
  st:signal xsd:decimal  # <-- datatype
}
```

([demo](http://rawgit.com/shexSpec/shex.js/master/doc/shex-simple.html?schema=PREFIX%20epri%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.epri.com%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20st%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.epri.com%2Fstudies%2F3002011786%3E%0APREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20tax%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Finfo.identifiers.org%2Ftaxonomy%2F%3E%0A%0Aepri%3AVariableShape%20%7B%0A%20%20a%20%5Bst%3AstudyVariable%5D%20%3B%0A%20%20st%3Asubject%20%5Btax%3A~%5D%20%3B%0A%20%20st%3Asignal%20xsd%3Adecimal%0A%7D&data=PREFIX%20epri%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.epri.com%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20tax%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Finfo.identifiers.org%2Ftaxonomy%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20st%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.epri.com%2Fstudies%2F3002011786%3E%0A%0Ast%3AenvFactorEMF%20a%20st%3AstudyVariable%20%3B%0A%20%20st%3Asubject%20tax%3A1758%20%3B%0A%20%20st%3Asignal%20-.00043%20.&shape-map=%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.epri.com%2Fstudies%2F3002011786envFactorEMF%3E%40epri%3AVariableShape&interface=human&regexpEngine=threaded-val-nerr))